# F# (FSharp) TypeProvider as ATOM and RSS Feed Reader

Tags: f#, rss, feed, atom-feed, type-providers

What is the best way for using **F# TypeProvider** as ATOM and RSS Feed Reader
for all versions of RSS 0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 1.0, 2.0 and ATOM 1.0?

I came to the conclusion

1. I need a sample file or url per version and format for the TypeProvider (XmlProvider)
2. download the feed, parse the header for format and version
3. switch for format and version to the corresponding TypeProvider instance and let them parse the feed

My question

Is there **a better or simpler way** of doing that (especially unifying the feed formats for easy access)?

Note

The .Net Framework class **SyndicationFeed** does not work very well on real world data, because of parsing-exceptions.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you could pass examples of all the different formats to the XmlProvider (and then handle different options dynamically) but the XML provider currently has a bug in this case: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/294. I'll see if we can fix that soon & will send an update!

Comment: @TomasPetricek Does this mean we can feed multiple formats/versions at once into the one instance of a XmlProvider? 
I found the definition:
'SampleIsList' If true, the children of the root in the sample document represent individual samples for the inference.
How is that handled internally? Will this not be very confusing?
My intention was to have one separate XmlProvider per format/version